# Problems with ng-show within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to show or hide one item of the list

```
<div class="row">
    <ul  ng-repeat="event in events">
        <div ng-show="event.name == event.name" ng-model="event.id">
        <p ><a href="list_stand.html#/home/{{event.id}}">{{event.name}}</a> <a ng-click="showScope($event)">show scope</a></p>
        <p>{{ event.address }}</p>
        <p>{{ event.init_date }}</p>
        <p>{{ event.final_date }}</p>
        <p><!--button type="button" name="btnBook2" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="book()">Book your place</button --></p>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul  ng-repeat-end></ul>
</div>
```

How can I access one of this event form the controller, so I can change the variable "event.name", so I can hide?

Comment: If you want to control each and every div from controller, why dont you try with directives?

Answer (score 0):

You can put some variable in your controller like, `completedEvent.name = someEvent;`

and change your HTML like below:

```
<div ng-show="completedEvent.name == event.name" ng-model="event.id">
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer me.... But from the controller, how can I identified the <div> number 1, o number 2? Thas is my problem.....From the controller I need to control every <div> by it's own.....  According to your answer, I can only control one of the DIV's......

Comment: I tried, what you said, but the same result.....The <div> won't show....